# Show that $S= \{ \left(\frac{i}{k},\frac{j}{nk} \right) : 0 \leq i < k, 0 \leq j < nk \} $ is an $(n,\epsilon)$-spanning set

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

Let $\mathbb{T}^2=\mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$. Let $T: \mathbb{T}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{T}^2$ be the transformation. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

$$T(x,y)=\left(x+\alpha \mod 1, x+y \mod 1 \right) $$.

One can show that $\displaystyle T^n(x,y)=\left(x+n\alpha \mod 1, y+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\alpha \mod 1 \right)$.

Show that if k is an integer such $\displaystyle\frac{1}{k}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, the set S given by

$$S= \left\{ \left(\frac{i}{k},\frac{j}{nk} \right) : 0 \leq i < k, 0 \leq j < nk \right\} $$

is an $(n,\epsilon)$-spanning set.

DEFINITION: Let $\epsilon >0, n \in \mathbb{N}$. A set $S \subset X$ is $(n,\epsilon)$-spanning set if for all $x \in X$, $\exists \ y \in S$ such that $d_n(x,y)< \epsilon$.

DEFINTION(ish): $\displaystyle d_n(x,y)=\max_{0 \leq k <n} d(f^k(x),f^k(y))$ for a given f (in this case T).

I draw a grid on the unit square $[0,1]^2$ given by $S$, but cannot see how to calculate $d_n(x,y)$.

Comment: Can someone please edit the \{ \} to make them bigger. I cant see how to do it.

Comment: This is strange. I think one should get a tighter net on the first coordinate, i.e. something like $S = \{ (i/(nk), j/k): \ 0 \leq i < nk, \ 0 \leq j < k \}$. Where did you find this? Could you check for any copy error?

Comment: Past exam paper. No error (in what Ive written).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to compute exactly $d_n$, but to bound it. I assume that the distance used on $\mathbb{T}^2$ is the following:

$$d((x,y),(x',y')) = \hat{d} (x,x')+ \hat{d} (y,y'),$$

where $\hat{d}$ is the distance on $\mathbb{T}^1$.

Let $n > 0$. Then, for all $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ in $\mathbb{T}^2$, for all $k < n$:

$$\hat{d} \left( x+k\alpha, x'+k \alpha \right) = \hat{d} \left(x, x'\right),$$

and:

$$\hat{d} \left( y+kx+\frac{k(k-1)}{2} \alpha, y'+kx'+\frac{k(k-1)}{2} \alpha \right) = \hat{d} \left( y+kx, y'+kx'\right) \leq \hat{d} \left( y, y'\right) + k \hat{d} (x,x').$$

Hence:

$$d \left( T^k (x,y), T^k (x',y') \right) \leq  (k+1) \hat{d} (x,x') + \hat{d} \left( y, y'\right).$$

Taking the maximum for all $k < n$, we finally get:

$$d_n \left( (x,y), (x',y') \right) \leq  n \hat{d} (x,x') + \hat{d} \left( y, y'\right).$$

Now, let $\varepsilon > 0$, let $k > \varepsilon^{-1}$, and:

$$S' := \left\{ \left( \frac{i}{nk}, \frac{j}{k}\right): \ 0 \leq i < nk, \ 0 \leq j < k \right\}.$$

Pick $(x,y) \in \mathbb{T}^2$. Then there exists $i$ such that $\hat{d} \left(x, i/(nk)\right) < \varepsilon/(2n)$, and there exists $j$ such that $\hat{d} \left(y, j/k\right) < \varepsilon/2$. From there,

$$d_n \left( \left(x,y \right), \left(\frac{i}{nk},\frac{j}{k} \right) \right) \leq n\hat{d} \left(x, \frac{i}{nk}\right)+ \hat{d} \left( y, \frac{j}{k} \right) < n\frac{\varepsilon}{2n} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon.$$

Hence, $S'$ is a $(n, \varepsilon)$-spanning set. It is also a $(n, \varepsilon)$-spanning set for the Euclidean distance, which is smaller than the distance I used.

Two remarks:

- I used the usual (translation invariant) distance on the circle $\mathbb{T}^1$. That allows me to gain a factor of $2$ in the definition of $S'$, since I only need to take $k > \varepsilon^{-1}$. If you work with the Euclidean distance on $[0,1)$, then you need to take $k \geq 2 \varepsilon^{-1}$ (otherwise, points close to $1$ are too far from the spanning set). Since I don't know the definition you took, I had to choose.
- The question as you stated is false, and you have to invert the coordinates in the definition of $S$.

Comment: 1) $\mathbb{T}^1$ is constructed by taking the unit invertal $[0,1]$ and wrapping it round so that $0 \sim 1$. It can be associated to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Not sure what your remark and the factor 2 means, if it is not important I will ignore it.

Comment: 2) Why do we need to invert the coordinates? I would have thought that you could still do it?

Comment: @1234: 1) Everything depends on the distance you use (and that you did not specify). If it's the usual distance on $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$, you don't need the $2$ factor. If it's the usual distance on $[0,1)$, which I have sometimes seen, you need the $2$ factor. Otherwise, a point close to $1$ won't be in a $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of the spanning set - the closest point is at distance roughly $1-1/k$, which is too far (On the circle, this point is actually close to $0$, so on a $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of the spanning set).

Comment: What are these usual distances? I thought I was just using some altered version of the euclidean distance?. What step doesnt work in your proof with inverted coordinates?

Comment: @1234: 2) Because there is an error in the exam. The balls for $d_n$ are not round, but quite flat. Roughly, the balls of radius $\varepsilon$ for $d_n$ spans $\varepsilon$ in the $y$ direction, but only $\varepsilon/n$ in the $x$ direction. Hence, they tend to be vertical, elongated ellipsoids. If you want to cover everything with such balls, you need your net to be denser in the $x$ direction. As it is done in your post, there is a lot of overlap, and a lot of space which is not in a $\varepsilon$ neighborhood of $S$ for $d_n$.

Comment: @1234: The usual distance on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ would be $\min\{|x-y|, |x-y+1|\}$. The usual distance on $[0,1)$ would be $|x-y|$. More to the piont: how does the exam defines $d$?

Comment: "induced by Euclidean distance"

Comment: @1234: so, the distance on $\mathbb{T}^1$ is $\min \{|x-y|, |x-y+1|, |x-y-1|\}$ (I forgot a term before), which is the $\hat{d}$ I used in my answer, and you don't need a factor $2$. So you can safely ignore the remark. That said, it would make a nice little exercise to see where my assertion "Then there exists $i$ such that [...]" comes from.